# Change Permissions Of A Channel Just Created

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the below code which is intended to create a new channel with a name. This works fine. It then needs to set the permissions of the channel to making it VIEW_CHANNEL false for all users. It then needs to overwrite permissions for the message author to grant them VIEW_CHANNEL. Im getting stuck on how to make the permissions apply on the channel just created.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

let botIcon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;
let ticketEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setDescription("TicketBot")
.setColor("#bc0000")
.setThumbnail(botIcon)
.addField("New Ticket", `${message.author} your ticket has been created.`);

let ticketchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "bot-testing");
if(!ticketchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find bot testing channel.");

ticketchannel.send(ticketEmbed);

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
let ticketid = getRandomInt(10000);
let name = `ticket-${message.author.username}-${ticketid}`;

message.guild.createChannel(name, "text")
.then(

    message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true
    })
);    
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "new"
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `message.channel`, try using the channel returned from createChannel, e.g. `message.guild.createChannel(name, "text").then(function(channel) { channel.overwritePermissions(message.author, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true }); });`

Comment: Also, maybe it would be a better idea to direct message the user their ticket rather than create a channel for it? Then you don't need to worry about conflicting names or the bot not having the permission to make a channel

Comment: Your suggested amendments didn't work, unfortunately. And it is required to be a channel as staff members will be replying to the ticket and assisting with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works :)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

let botIcon = bot.user.displayAvatarURL;
let ticketEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setDescription("TicketBot")
.setColor("#bc0000")
.setThumbnail(botIcon)
.addField("New Ticket", `${message.author} your ticket has been created.`);

let ticketchannel = message.guild.channels.find(`name`, "bot-testing");
if(!ticketchannel) return message.channel.send("Couldn't find bot testing channel.");

ticketchannel.send(ticketEmbed);

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
let ticketid = getRandomInt(10000);
let name = `ticket-${message.author.username}-${ticketid}`;

message.guild.createChannel(name, "text")
.then(m => {
    m.overwritePermissions(message.guild.id, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: false
    })

    m.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, {
        VIEW_CHANNEL: true
    })
})
//channel.delete()
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "new"
}
```