# Create synced category and channel

Tags: node.js, discord.js

If you create a new child channel manually it will be synced to the category; but if I create one with js it's not.

I've spent hours googling and reading docs and I can't find anything.
This is what I use to create the channel:

```
message.guild.createChannel("Test", 'text').then(m => {
  m.setParent(category.id);
});
```

Manually created:

[image: Synced channel Example]

JS-created:

[image: Unsynced channel Example]

I can set the permissions manually but I was really hoping to create them synced.

Comment: Related (possibly even duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210784/change-permissions-of-a-channel-just-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I discovered that this doesn't work because of a bug in the library. The bug has been fixed in the `11.4-dev` branch with [this PR](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/pull/2800).
If you want to use it, you'll need to either wait this version is stable or use it while its being developed.

The way you're creating the channel is right.
For the permissions, try using [`TextChannel.lockPermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=lockPermissions): it should bind the permissions of that channel to the ones of the parent (the category channel).

```
message.guild.createChannel("Test", 'text').then(async m => {
  await m.setParent(category.id);
  await m.lockPermissions();
});
```

Comment: I had to change it a little to allow it to run by wrapping setParent on its own `.then(m => m.setParent(category.id))`; but it doesn't appear to do what I want. 
ps. I was testing formats.

Comment: I edited my answer: didn't notice that `.setParent()` is async. Try again with this code.

Comment: It runs correct but doesn't sync the permissions, This puts me in the right direction so I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I found it out: this code is right, it doesn't work because of a bug in the lib. You find more details in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help! I hate to ask for any more; but how would I go about installing the dev branch? `npm install discord.js@11.4-dev` didn't work

Comment: Solved it. I just made the changes to my files they did. it works perfectly you're a lifesaver!